# Why isn't passed quoted $@ a single argument?

Tags: bash, quoting, string

Why isn't passed quoted `$@` a single argument?

```
f2()
{
        echo "f2: $1"
}

f1()
{
        local x=("$@")
        f2 "${x[@]}"
}

f1 x y
```

Invocation:

```
$ bash t537.sh
f2: x
```

Here I expect that `x y` is printed because `${x[@]}` is passed to `f2` in quoted form.

Why passing quoted `${x[@]}` passes `"x" "y"` rather than passing `"x y"`?

P.S. It seems that [`"$*"`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15692004/1778275) may be the solution here. However, I'm trying to understand why `"${x[@]}"` does not work here.

Comment: In short: Because `"$@"` is a special magical thingy, which makes an exception to the general rule. And for very good reasons. (the same applies to `"${array[@]}"` by extension)

Comment: I was about to post what @ikkachy already commented. But I'd add: in the general case, using `"$@"` is very much more often the right thing to do, as it keeps together arguments that contains separators (spaces, tabs). for exemple if you have 3 files: `file1` `file2 with spaces` `file3` and write a script that asks the filenames as arguments, the 2nd should be entered with quotes `"file2 with spaces"` and these should stay together. The `"$@"` would allow you to do that, whereas `"$*"` or `$*` or `$@` would not. Other use case : https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_arg_in_.24.2A

Comment: Note that, I don't see it explicitly mentioned in the linked post, but if you did `x=$@` or `x="$@"`, you'd get the args (positional parameters) joined to a single string. But the details vary between the shells, so better use `$*` there if joining them is what you want.

Comment: @ilkkachu Thanks. FYI: 1) By doing `("$@")` I [convert command line arguments into an array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12711837/1778275), 2) I've fixed my code via `echo "f2: $@"`.

Comment: @pmor, yes, that works too since `echo` joins its args with spaces. But that's a feature of echo, and e.g. printf would be different there. if you have the args `foo` and `bar`, then `echo "f2: $@"` will run echo with the two args `f2: foo` and `bar`. While  `echo "f2: $*"` would pass just the single arg `f2: foo bar` (assuming the default `IFS`)

Comment: So for example, `printf "f2: %s\n" "$@"` and `printf "f2: %s\n" "$*"` produce very different results.